# Move one form to another winforms - C#

Tags: winforms, mdi

I have 2 winforms Form 1 and Form 2. I have button1 in form1, when i click on button1 from form1 i display form2.

```
            Form2 ins = new Form2();
            ins.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
            this.Hide();
            ins.ShowDialog();
```

I hide the form1 to display form2 when button1 is clicked. This creates a flicking effect and i need to remove this flicking. How do i open/redirect to another form (i am supposed to show only one form at a time and am not supposed to show any top menu like (if i use MDIParent form). Just one active form.

Thanks,
Karthick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds a bit like you're trying to create a web-style UI where the user steps from one "page" (represented by a Form) to another.

Rather than implementing a UI like this with separate forms, you're better off doing it with UserControls hosted on a single parent form.

Have a read of this MSDN article, which includes a download with sample code. It's a great walkthrough for designing that kind of user interface:

[IUIs and Web-Style Navigation in Windows Forms, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951103.aspx)

[IUIs and Web-Style Navigation in Windows Forms, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951278.aspx)

**Edit**

If you're intent on showing two separate forms, is there any reason you need to show the second one modally? Can you not simply show it and then hide the original?

```
form2.Show();
form1.Hide();
```

... or do you have yet another form that both form1 and form2 are "modal" to?

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have more forms but at one instant only one form should be visible.

Answer (score 3):

To transfer from one page (`form1`) to another (`form2`) 
      suppose `form1` contain a button named "SAVE"
         we have to write the following code in click event of the "SAVE" button

```
form2 f2=new form2();
f2.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a property on winforms if you would like to show it on the task bar or not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hide use close option.

```
Form1 formObject = new Form1();
formObject.Close();
```

or simply

```
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can clarify your doubt about how to redirect from one form1 to form2

for example:
place a link in form1 and then write following code in it

```
form2 ins=new form2();
ins.show();
```