# windows form using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, window

I am new to windows form using c#. I have to create a login form and then need to show logged in user relevant data from reading xml.
Should I create two different form for login and showing data or should I create only on form and make disappear login control and show data in the same form?
If I go with having two forms than how to make disappear login form and show second window form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move one form to another winforms - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463513/move-one-form-to-another-winforms-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create two diferents forms and hide the login form

for hide the form you can use

`this.hide()`

for show the form you must create an instance the next form:

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier with two forms. If you use Windows Forms you could show your loginform as Dialog: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

After that you could load your mainform like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ws1btzy8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx